# Pervasive PSQL Control Centre / Currency data type

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

Having issues updating a Pervasive PSQL table using Pervasive Control Centre and wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction. I'm struggling to update a field in the table whose type is '254-VB Currency'.

Sample query: 
Update TABLE set "remBal" = 100.00 where 'Posting' = 215288;

The value that ends up in the remBal field is 463673729135463.6288

Pervasive version is v10.30. Updating via e.g. VAccess control works fine. It's just Pervasive Control Centre that doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VAccess control supports more data types than the standard PSQL engine does.  The VB Currency data type is not one that's natively supported in PSQL.
According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/currency-data-type), the Currency data type is defined as:

> Currency variables are stored as 64-bit (8-byte) numbers in an integer
>   format, scaled by 10,000 to give a fixed-point number with 15 digits
>   to the left of the decimal point and 4 digits to the right. This
>   representation provides a range of -922,337,203,685,477.5808 to
>   922,337,203,685,477.5807.

What I would suggest, is enter 100.00 to the database using VAccess, then look at the value in Control Center.  You can then use that value in your SQL statement.  It's not pretty but it might work.